# Как разместить элементы массива в отдельной строке в HIVE?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

У меня есть таблица
струтктура таблицы такова:

```
Name - string 
Contract - string 
Dates - array of string
```

Пример записи таков

```
Andrew|SEC2185|["20180302","20180305"]
Anton |SEC2185|["20181212","20181010"]
```

Необходимо внутренними средствами HIVE расположить элементы массива в отельной строке и получить таблицу вида:

```
Andrew|SEC2185|"20180302"
Andrew|SEC2185|"20180305"
Anton |SEC2185|"20181212"
Anton |SEC2185|"20181010"
```

Данные сервера: HIVE 2.2.0.

Может есть идеи хоть какие нибудь?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Дат всегда две? тогда тупо (с точностью до синтаксиса) `SELECT name, contract, dates[1] FROM table UNION ALL SELECT name, contract, dates[2] FROM table`

Comment: Это моя ошибка. Нужно было указать. Дат может быть до 10.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону чего-то вроде `SELECT name, contract, explode(dates) AS onedate FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать метод `explode` для "разворачивания" массива. Только в Hive нужно использовать его в связке с выражением `LATERAL VIEW`:

```sql
SELECT name, contract, date
FROM table LATERAL VIEW explode(dates) adTable AS date;
```